# When was smartctl last run?

Tags: smartctl, smart

I use `smartctl -t long` to execute full surface test on a drive, it automatically closes then the test is run in background.

Then I use `smartctl -H` to view the result. But it doesn't say how long ago the reported test was done, or if there's one running at the moment.

Is there any way to know it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smartctl -a` will show you the relevant information, including in particular the drive’s age (in power-on hours) and the times at which the last self-tests ran; this will give you some idea of how long ago they ran. For example,

```
...
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       14910
...
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14898         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14874         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14850         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     14837         -
...
```

tells me that this particular drive ran a short test twelve hours ago, and an extended offline test 73 hours ago. (The drive runs 24/7.)

`smartctl -c` can show whether a test is ongoing, but see `man smartctl` for details and caveats.

Comment: Thanks! Where do u see it ran a short test 12h ago and an extended test 73h ago?

Comment: When I ran `smartctl`, the drive had been powered on for a total of 14910h; the last short test had run when the drive was 14898h “old”, 12h earlier, and the last extended test when it was 14837h “old”, 73h earlier.

Comment: oh got it we have to subtract them

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you're running your disk 24 hours a day, or some certain hours each day, you can programmatically calculate when you last ran a smartctl test, but other than that - no way. Disk drives/SSDs only store the seconds they've been running (and then if you unplug them without properly shutting them down, it's not certain whether they can store this data).